# Show that if $A$ is closed in $Y$ and $Y$ is closed in $X$, then $A$ is closed in $X$.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Show that if $A$ is closed in $Y$ and $Y$ is closed in $X$, then $A$ is closed in $X$.

Proof: Since $A\subset Y \subset X$, we have $A^c=X-A=(Y-A)\cup (X-Y)$. Then by the properties of closed sets, the set $A$ being closed in $Y$ and $Y$ being closed in $X$ implies that $A^c=Y-A$ is open in $Y$ and also $Y^c=X-Y$ is open in $X$. Therefore $A^c$ is the union of open sets and hence is open. Equivalently, $A$ is closed in $X$.

Is this correct?

Comment: $\{Y-A\}$ is a set with one element, namely the set $Y-A$.  Just say $Y-A$.

Comment: Thank you @Randall - the curly brackets were not intended. Instead, I have now used () to differentiate what is being unioned.

Comment: This proof does not work.  $Y-A$ is open in $Y$, but it may not be open in $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ is closed in $Y$ and $Y$ closed in $X$ then there exists two closed sets $F$ and $G$ such that $A = F \cap Y$ and $Y = G \cap X$.
We deduce that :
$$A = F \cap Y = F \cap (G \cap X) = (F \cap G) \cap X$$
then $A$ is closed in $X$ since $F \cap G$ is closed.

Answer (score 2):

Your set-up works but be precise:

$A$ is closed in $Y$ means $Y-A$ is open in $Y$ so $Y-A = O_1 \cap Y$ for some open set $O_1$ in $X$. In particular $Y-A \subseteq O_1$.

$Y$ is closed in $X$ means $X-Y$ is open in $X$.

It follows that $$(X-Y) \cup O_1 = X-A$$ is open in $X$ and so $A$ is closed in $X$.

Answer (score 1):

As Randall said, your answer is not correct. However, your idea is good and you just have to correct the wrong passage : $Y - A$ may be open in $X$.

Use the definition of the induced topology of $Y$ to find an open subset $Z$ of $X$ such that $$Y-A = Z \cap Y.$$ Use the open set $Z$ instead of $Y-A$ in your answer.

Comment: Are you saying that $Z\cup (X\setminus Y)=X\setminus A$?

Comment: Exactly. I didn't want to write it to let pyridoxal_trigeminus understand it.